# React Native: Rendering an Image component with uri provided through state variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, promise, react-native-firebase

A React Native learner here.
I am trying to render a Functional Component as shown below.
I am fetching the URI through the firebase which get fetched after 1-2 seconds time lag.
Once fetched, I update my state variable.

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

const SearchResultCard = ()=>{
  const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState('https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/200000/nahled/plain-red-background.jpg');  // Some placeholder image.
  var storageRef = storage().ref();
  storageRef.child("photos/flower.jpg").getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{console.log(url); setImageURL(url);});  // setting the valid image URL 

  setTimeout(()=> console.log("++++URL fetched: ", imageURL), 2000);  // prints a correct URL after 2 seconds.

  return (
  <View>
    <Image style={styles.SearchResultImage}
          source={{
            uri:
            {imageURL},
          }}
    />
  </View>
  );
}

....
....rendering the SearchResultCard Component
....
```

However in device, it shows error:

[image]

I confirmed, fetching of URL after obvious time lag is successful.
My confusion here is, how I can provide `Image` source.uri through state variable ?
Providing a hardcoded url works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uri` property accept the string url, and you are passing url as object. Please pass string in `uri` as below :

```js
<Image 
  style={styles.SearchResultImage}
  source={{
    uri: imageURL, // remove braces
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Such silly mistake took 3 hours. I am truly a noob.